# String one unreliably found in string two

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char

What is wrong in this code? It receives two strings and determines if string one is contained in string two. Sometimes it works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[1000], b[1000];
    int k = -1;
    int salir = 0;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        for (int j = k + 1; j < strlen(b); j++)
        {
            if (a[i] = b[j])
            {
                k = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (a[i] = b[k + 1])
        {
            salir = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            salir = 1;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (salir == 0)
        cout << "Si esta contenido" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "No esta contenido" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's so bad about [`std::str::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr)?

Answer (score 5):

One error is:

```
if(a[i]=b[j]){
  k=j;
  break; 
}
```

should be:

```
if(a[i] == b[j]){
      //^^logical comparison, not assignment
  k=j;
  break; 
  }
```

Similar error can be found at other places.

Comment: Jajaja but if i do this the programm doe not work well!

Comment: @SergioOvalle What errors are you getting? That helps us to find the problem you know.

Comment: And the best advice for this error is to let your compiler find them for you by turning on the warnings.